# Prove that $(\mathbb{R}^2,d_2)$ and $(\mathbb{R}^2,d_1)$ are not isometric, where $d_2$ is euclidean metric and $d_1$ is absolute value metric.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces, normed-spaces, isometry

> Prove that $(\mathbb{R}^2,d_2)$ and $(\mathbb{R}^2,d_1)$, are not isometric where $d_2$ is euclidean metric and $d_1$ is absolute value metric.

I have to show that there cannot exist a map from $(\mathbb{R}^2,d_2)$ to $(\mathbb{R}^2,d_1)$ that preserves length. But I didn't get any idea.

Comment: What are $d_2$ and $d_1$?

Comment: I have edited the question

Answer (score 7):

Consider the points $p=(1,0)$ and $q=(0,1)$. Then $d_1(p,q)=2$ and both points $(0,0)$ and $(1,1)$ are such that their distance both to $p$ and to $q$ is equal to $1$.

However, in $(\mathbb R^2,d_2)$, whenever you have two points $p$ and $q$ such that $d_2(p,q)=2$, the only point whose distance to both of them is $1$ is $\frac{p+q}2$; there is no other point for which this is true.

Comment: how there is only one point $\frac{p+q}{2}$

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: Can you prove that there is only one point whose distance from both p and q is 1?

Comment: If the distance from a point $r$ to $p$ is $1$, then $r$ belongs to the circle centered at $p$ with radius $1$. And if the distance from $r$ to $q$ is also $1$, then $r$ belongs to the circle centered at $q$ with radius $1$. But the distance from $p$ to $q$ is $2$, and so those two circles have a single intersection point.

Answer (score 1):

With $d_1\bigl((x,y),(u,v)\bigr)=|x-u|+|y-v|$, we have
$$ (0,0),\quad (1,0), \quad (\tfrac12,\tfrac12)$$
and 
$$ (0,0),\quad (0,1), \quad (\tfrac12,\tfrac12),$$
that is,  two equilateral triangles with side length $1$ and common edge and the other vertices have distance $2$.

Under the Euclidean metric, we would always have distance $\sqrt 3$ instead of $2$.